# VB.NET browser click event handler: value of '0' is not valid for 'index' error

Tags: vb.net, onclick, event-handling

I have tried to make a small program using [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET).

When it opens, it shows a webpage and a process bar underneath the webpage. When the user clicks the link in the  webpage, the progess bar stops processing and show a `You clicked a link` message. When processing is complete it shows another message which says: `Thanks for helping me`.

I wrote the code for the total process in VB.NET, but when I debug it it shows a message:

> Value of '0' is not valid for 'index'. 'index' should be between 0 and -1.
>   Parameter name: index

My code is:

```
 Public Class MyPage
    Private Sub MyPage_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Timer1.Interval = 1500
    End Sub

    Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
        WebBrowser1.Document.Links(0).AttachEventHandler("onclick", AddressOf LinkClick)
    End Sub

    Sub LinkClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Timer1.Start()
        MsgBox("You clicked the link", , "Clicked The link")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        ProgressBar1.Increment(2)
        If ProgressBar1.Value = 100 Then
            Timer1.Stop()
            ProgressBar1.Value = 0
            MsgBox("Thanks for help me", , "Thankssss!")
        End If
    End Sub
 End Class
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

You blindly assume that the page will always have a link.  Wrong assumption.  Fix:

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
    If WebBrowser1.Document.Links.Count > 0 Then
        WebBrowser1.Document.Links(0).AttachEventHandler("onclick", AddressOf LinkClick)
    End If
End Sub
```

Or given the usage, the more sane:

```
    For Each link As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.Links
        link.AttachEventHandler("onclick", AddressOf LinkClick)
    Next
```

Comment: You forgot the closing parenthesis on the second line of the second example.

Comment: Thanks Hans Passant for reply. 

I used

`
    Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
        If WebBrowser1.Document.Links.Count > 0 Then
            WebBrowser1.Document.Links(0).AttachEventHandler("onclick", AddressOf LinkClick)
        End If
    End Sub
`

But time not started when click a link from website.

Comment: Well, of course not, the page doesn't actually have any links.  Which is why your original code threw an exception.

Comment: Sorry Hans, I don't understand clearly. I want that, When I click any link from visible page in WebBrowser1 then timer start. If I can't click any link in page, nothing else. but when click on a link from page, timer need to start.

I'm fully new here & VB, so if you write this for me here its very helpful for me.

Comment: Hello Hans, Please reply. I really need your help.